# How do I sync my system clock via the internet?

Tags: 14.04, time

My system says it's 15:00 even though it's 21:00, and this means HTTPs stops working on sites such as google!

I've gone onto System Preferences, selected my location, and clicked 'automatically from the internet' but the time bizarrely stays 6 hours to early.

How can I solve this problem is system preferences? Or, on the command line? I need to sync with Helsinki time.

Comment: Is your time zone data correct? Run `date -u` and make sure that your system's UTC time is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using regular Ubuntu, click on the clock in the top right.

Choose "Time & Date settings".

Make sure your time zone is correct on the map. Click your location if it is wrong.

At the bottom of the window, it says "Set the time:". There should be an option for "Automatically from the internet". Click it and close the window.

I hope that helps.